# Django - Exclude a value from a .value_list

Tags: python, django

Greeting everyone, I trying to filter a specific value list from my model below is my code :

```
employee_name = WorkOrder.objects.filter(
                    project_id=48
                 ).values_list(
                    'assign_to__official_name', flat=True
                 ).distinct()
print(employee_name)
```

and this is the output I receive

```
<QuerySet ['JOHN', 'GEOFF', 'KYLE', 'NONE', 'BRUCE', 'CLARK',]>
```

How can I exclude the value `'NONE'` from this queryset based on its value and not its ID?

Anyhelp is much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#exclude)

> Returns a new QuerySet containing objects that do not match the given lookup parameters.

```
WorkOrder.objects.filter(...).exclude(assign_to__official_name='NONE').values_list(...
```

Comment: 5th answer where i am late today!!

Comment: @NoobEditor - If you have an answer of your own that better answers the question its always worth adding it as another answer :)

Comment: nope, same stuff...i think m thinking like everyone else in answer...just late thinking..lol!!!

Comment: @NoobEditor, Thanks you this works! much appreciated!